# Using SMACH to monitor robot battery level

Tags: ros, executive-smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to program the following simple scenario using SMACH.

The robot monitors its battery level on a topic called /battery_level using a SMACH MonitorState which is part of the state machine SM_MONITOR_BATTERY.  In the meantime, the robot navigates around a series of waypoints in succession using a state machine SM_NAV_WAYPOINTS.

I want the overall state machine to behave as follows:  If the battery level falls below a threshold (SM_MONITOR_BATTERY returns 'invalid'), SM_MONITOR_BATTERY transitions to another state called RECHARGE that moves the robot to the docking station (NAV_DOCKING_STATION) and recharges the robot.  In the meantime, the SM_NAV_WAYPOINT machine is paused or terminated until the battery is recharged (SM_MONITOR_BATTERY returns 'valid').

I can make both the recharging behavior and the waypoint navigation behavior work on their own but I have only a vague idea how they can be combined using the Concurrence container.  I've tried for days to get the right syntax and I have failed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

--patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92891/using-smach-to-monitor-robot-battery-level/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2013-10-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds similar to something I had to do last year - I posted a simplified version of my final state machine [here](http://wiki.ros.org/smach/Tutorials/State%20Machine%20Preemption%20with%20MonitorState).

However, I assume that you already found that, and it hasn't helped. You might get better answers if you post what you've tried so far about and ask what's wrong with it.

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-10-22**:
Hi Linzey--I think this is exactly what I need so many thanks!  You're right--I did read your Wiki page some time ago but forgot where it was until now.